# improve the format produced from org's babel source code

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Upon learning pandas on org mode of emacs, tried the following codes:

```
scientists = pd.DataFrame(
data={'Occupation': ['Chemist', 'Statistician'],
'Born': ['1920-07-25', '1876-06-13'],
'Died': ['1958-04-16', '1937-10-16'],
'Age': [37, 61]},
index=['Rosaline Franklin', 'William Gosset'],
columns=['Occupation', 'Born', 'Died', 'Age'])
print(scientists)
```

Jupyter produced

[image]

Unfortunately, the org's babel does not produce very pretty format

[image: format]

The header was not placed in correct column.

How could improve the format ?

Answer (score 0):

The following org file works perfectly AFAICT:

```
* pandas

#+begin_src python :results output
import pandas as pd

scientists = pd.DataFrame(
data={'Occupation': ['Chemist', 'Statistician'],
'Born': ['1920-07-25', '1876-06-13'],
'Died': ['1958-04-16', '1937-10-16'],
'Age': [37, 61]},
index=['Rosaline Franklin', 'William Gosset'],
columns=['Occupation', 'Born', 'Died', 'Age'])
print(scientists)

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:                      Occupation        Born        Died  Age
: Rosaline Franklin       Chemist  1920-07-25  1958-04-16   37
: William Gosset     Statistician  1876-06-13  1937-10-16   61
```

The org mode version is `Org mode version 9.2.3 (release_9.2.3-367-gd79e80)`

EDIT: I'm guessing the culprit is `:session`. There seems to be a bug where it throws away initial spaces on a line when it copies the output. I'm getting this in the session buffer:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, May 11 2019, 00:45:16) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 


'org_babel_python_eoe'
                     Occupation        Born        Died  Age
Rosaline Franklin       Chemist  1920-07-25  1958-04-16   37
William Gosset     Statistician  1876-06-13  1937-10-16   61
>>> >>> >>> >>> 'org_babel_python_eoe'
>>>
```

but the results in the org buffer are:

```
#+RESULTS:
: Python 3.7.3 (default, May 11 2019, 00:45:16) 
: [GCC 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)] on linux
: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
: Occupation        Born        Died  Age
: Rosaline Franklin       Chemist  1920-07-25  1958-04-16   37
: William Gosset     Statistician  1876-06-13  1937-10-16   61
```

In addition to the extra junk that does not get properly filtered out (likely a result of my faulty setup), the initial space in front of the header is completely gone.